# Two different formulas

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, vectors, differentiation

My problem is simple : given a particle of mass $m$, charge $q$ and velocity $\bf{v}$. If $\bf{A}$ denotes the magnetic potential satisfying $\bf{B}= \nabla \times \bf{A}$. 
I want to etablish the laws of motion in the theory of special relativity for this particle.

And the problem is that I need to compute $\nabla (\bf{v} \cdot \bf{A})$.

I read on several textbooks that : $$\nabla (\bf{v} \cdot \bf{A}) = \bf{v} \times (\nabla \times \bf{A}) + (\bf{v} \cdot \nabla) \bf{A} $$

The problem is that the general formula according to wikipedia is $$\nabla (\bf{v} \cdot \bf{A}) = \bf{v} \times (\nabla \times \bf{A}) + \bf{A} \times (\nabla \times \bf{v})+ (\bf{v} \cdot \nabla) \bf{A} + (\bf{A} \cdot \nabla) \bf{v}  $$

[with general vectors $\bf{v}$ and $\bf{A}$]

So I don't understand why $\bf{A} \times (\nabla \times \bf{v})+(\bf{A} \cdot \nabla) \bf{v} =0$ if one does not make any other assumption over $\bf{v}$ and $\bf{A}$.

I think people here have encouter this prolem so please if you walk by and know, just give me a hint of a link.

Comment: Is your $\mathbf{v}$ constant?

Comment: $\bf{v}$ is not supposed constant

Comment: Could be implied Feynman notation, that is, $\nabla$ operates only on $\mathbf A$ and not $\mathbf v$

Comment: But $\bf{v}$ is the velocity of the ponctual particle $m$ lacated at $\bf{r}$ so $\bf{v}=0$ except at $\bf{r}$. Could it be that ?

Comment: I suppose that for the general formula $\mathbf v$ is assumed to be a vector field. For a point-like particle differentiation of its velocity doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: Hi M.LTA. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: I removed the homework and exercise tag that someone added, so what do you not understand with that ? I am working on special relativity on my own I am not a student in physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the relativistic lagrangian:
$$\mathcal{L} = -m_{0}c^2\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} + q \vec{A} \cdot \vec{v}$$
Equations of motion are derived from:
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_{i}} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}_{i}} = 0$$
In our case:
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_{i}} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i}}(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{v}) = \vec{v} \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial x_{i}}$$
We do not differentiate over $\vec{v} = \dot{\vec{x}}$, cause it is an independent variable in Lagrange formalism.
More generally:
$$\nabla (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{v})$$
and it only acts on magnetic potential $\vec{A}$, so we can write (summation convention):
$$\begin{align}
\left[ \nabla (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{v})\right]_{i} & = v_{j} \nabla_{i} A_{j} \\[3mm]
& = v_{j} \nabla_{i} A_{j} - v_{j}\nabla_{j}A_{i} + v_{j}\nabla_{j}A_{i} \\[3mm]
& = \left(\delta_{i l} \delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl} \right) v_{j} \nabla_{l} A_{m} + v_{j}\nabla_{j}A_{i} \\[3mm]
& = \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm}v_{j}\nabla_{l}A_{m} + v_{j}\nabla_{j}A_{i} \\[3mm]
& = \left[ \vec{v} \times (\nabla \times \vec{A}) + (\vec{v} \cdot \nabla) \vec{A} \right]_{i}
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is what I was trying to calculate ;) I don't really understand your "cause $\vec{v} = \dot {\vec{x}}$ " but in my opinion since $\bf{v}$ is not a really a vector field we have the result but it is not clear ...

Answer (score 1):

In Lagrangian formalism you have two types of variables $q = q(t)$ and $\dot q = \dot q(t)$. These variables are functions of time (this implies $\partial_{i}q = 0$ and $\partial_{i}\dot q = 0 \text{ for } i = \{1, 2, 3\}$). This is how Lagrangian works, otherwise one would have something really complicated

From Nex_Friedrich's answer follows that $q := \vec x$ and $\dot q: = \dot{ \vec x} = \vec v $. Thus you see that in our case $\nabla \dot q = \nabla \vec v = 0$.

That's how you can justify rule from wikipedia.